# Is there a way to change the Version 4.8.03752 SP1Rel to Version 4.7.03056

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to visual studio and working on the vb.net. I'm working on a project where my senior is using visual studio 2019 with Version 4.7.03056 and I'm using version 4.8.03752 SP1Rel.

How to change my version to 4.7.03056?

Comment: This might be an A/B problem.  Presumably, there is an incompatibility that is causing build problems; there may be a way to address the build problem without mucking around with your VS version.

Comment: you both should use .net 4.8 as this is last classic .net version. .net 5.0 will be technically .net core version.

Comment: .Net FW 4.8 has a number of improvements. See if it's possible to align everything to that version instead of going back to 4.7. If you really need to, install that version and set it as the Framework version of your Projects. If you haven't used anything specific to 4.8, you won't have to change anything.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, when i ran the code , i did not face any problems with the code, i will do as Jimi suggested and  check again:), thanks for the quick help

Answer (score 0):

Check the Application page of the project properties on your colleague's machine and see whether it is targeting .NET Framework 4.7, 4.7.1 or 4.7.2. I'm not sure which that version number corresponds to. Once you know, you can open the project properties on your own machine and select the same version. If it's not listed, run the VS Installer, open the list of individual components and select that version to install.

Comment: sounds like a plan, i will do as suggested, thanks for the help :)